# Replace content in visual basic web browser

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Suppose the following html code is present in web page

```
<td id="tdwords" colspan="2" class="inputWrap">
       <label for="words">Search term</label><input type="text" name="words" value="" id="words" title="Search Crystallography Journals Online" />
     </td>
```

How do I replace

```
id="tdwords"
```

with

```
id="tdset"
```

when a webpage is opened in my visual basic web browser?

Comment: Check [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/115467-edit-html-in-webbrowser/), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13768310/how-to-edit-html-using-the-webbrowser-control-turn-on-wysiwyg-features), or edit the file, save it and load it back in like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405608/importing-a-local-html-file-code-into-a-webbrowser). For basic edits, [this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?416275-Manipulate-Change-Form-Fill-data-in-webpages-using-the-Webbrowser-control/page2) should be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use javascript I believe.

Example:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    change_id();
});

function change_id() {
    var ids = document.getElementsByClassName('inputwrap'),
        i = ids.length;

    while(i--) {
        ids[i].setAttribute("id", "tdset") ;
    }
}
<script>"
```

Just put this in the Head content and it should happen.